# apply nested box in soul package

Tags: soul, underline

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

% \usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\begin{document}
\ulposdef\ulpgfC[xoffset=.15em]{%
  \ifulstarttype{0}%
    {\def\arr{|}}%
    {\def\arr{<}}%
  \ifulendtype{0}%
    {\edef\arr{\arr-|}}%
    {\edef\arr{\arr->}}%
  \raisebox{-.7ex}{%
    \tikz
    \draw[\arr,color=black!40,
          line width=1pt]
    (0,0) -- +(\ulwidth-1pt,0);}}

\ulpgfC{this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a textthis a textthisthis a text this a text  this a text this a text this a text this a textthis a textthisthis a textthis this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text v this a text this a text this a text this a textthis a text v this a text}

\end{document}

\_________________________________________________________________________
        \documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{soulpos}
    \begin{document}
    \ulposdef\ulpgfC[xoffset=.15em]{%
      \ifulstarttype{0}%
        {\def\arr{|}}%
        {\def\arr{<}}%
      \ifulendtype{0}%
        {\edef\arr{\arr-|}}%
        {\edef\arr{\arr->}}%
      \raisebox{-.7ex}{%
        \tikz
        \draw[\arr,color=black!40,
              line width=1pt]
        (0,0) -- +(\ulwidth-1pt,0);}}
    
    \newbox\mine
    \sbox\mine{\ulpgfC{a text this a text xtthis this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text v this a text this a text this a text this a textthis a text v this a text}}
    \ulpgfC{this a text this a text this  this a text this a textthis {\usebox\mine} a textthisthis a text this a text  this a text this a text this a text this a textthis a textthisthis a textthis this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text v this a text this a text this a text this a textthis a text v this a text}
    
    \end{document}
```

I am trying to use a nested macro which is made by "soulpos" package. whenever tried that, an error,reconstruction failed, raise by latex. can you pls share with me your solution?[image]

Comment: you can't nest soul commands, see the documentation of soul.

Comment: Yes we can but before using we should make a box like this: \newbox \bala bla      \sbox \blabla then in the soul macro  {\usebox\blabla}. Problem start when i want to write multiline text in it.

Comment: that is what I meant: you can't nest them, if you want to retain the break ability.

Comment: I have 2 more question also: why tex did not recognize some of macro (tex will highlight them as you see in the picture)? Is it possible to simulate making a paragraph by using boxes and glues and other things which we need? If it is possible pls give me reference. Thanks alot

Comment: it is not tex but your editor texstudio which does the highlighting. I have no idea what you need and what you mean by your question.

Comment: I need to make a nested underlined text with some text under. I have worked on that in different ways by different package like stack engine and zref but it does not let me break the line so i am thinking of making a paragraph with pure tex!!! So do you have better solution?

Comment: use lualatex and the lua-ul package. It allows nesting.

Comment: If I run your code (with and without `\usepackage{soul}`), it works fine, no errors. I'm using recent versions of the packages; maybe you have to update.

Comment: can you pls share your code with me? thanks a see .

Comment: The code is the one you show above. The output may not be what you want, but it does not give any errors.

Comment: Do you know how we can recognize end of each line in latex? I maen is there anyway to find it?

Comment: @gernot the example compiles but the screenshot shows a different code (with a nested command).